# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Pivot Usage?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a formatting issue. I have a table that gets populated. The table is row-based. However I need to have the table output as column based. I think I need a pivot?

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[phasepivot](
    [pinterval] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [phasetype] [smallint] NULL,
    [abegdate] [date] NULL,
    [abegdatehr] [smallint] NULL,
    [penddate] [date] NULL,
    [pendhour] [smallint] NULL,
    [alength] [int] NULL,
    [avglength] [money] NULL,
    [achgprevhilo] [money] NULL,
    [avgchgprev] [money] NULL,
    [achgprevhilopct] [money] NULL,
    [avgchgprevpct] [money] NULL,
    [adatehilo] [date] NULL,
    [ahilovalue] [money] NULL,
    [philovalue] [money] NULL,
    [aperiodstohilo] [int] NULL,
    [avgperiodstohilo] [money] NULL,
    [anumhilos] [int] NULL,
    [pnumhilos] [money] NULL,
    [projphaselen] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [recperiodstohilo] [int] NULL,
    [recchgprevhilo] [money] NULL,
    [recchgprevhilopct] [money] NULL,
    [reclength] [money] NULL,
    [avalue] [money] NULL,
    [LTL] [money] NULL,
    [UTL] [money] NULL,
    [nxtphstype] [smallint] NULL,
    [nxtphsdate] [date] NULL,
    [nxtphshour] [smallint] NULL,
    [nxtphshilo] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

It contains this data

pinterval   phasetype   abegdate    abegdatehr  penddate    pendhour    alength avglength   achgprevhilo    avgchgprev  achgprevhilopct avgchgprevpct   adatehilo   ahilovalue  philovalue  aperiodstohilo  avgperiodstohilo    anumhilos   pnumhilos   projphaselen    recperiodstohilo    recchgprevhilo  recchgprevhilopct   reclength   avalue  LTL UTL nxtphstype  nxtphsdate  nxtphshour  nxtphshilo
H   1   2013-09-26  3   2013-09-27  1   12  6.00    -16.74  -20.9827    -0.0098 -0.0153 2013-09-27  1687.11 1682.8673   6   5.00    4   3.00    extended    3   -20.9827    -0.0153 6.4786  1691.75 1690.7904   1694.8193   2   2013-09-27  2   1709.5498
D   1   2013-09-25  0   2013-10-01  0   3   5.00    -37.98  -55.4949    -0.0219 -0.0442 2013-09-25  1687.11 1571.9751   1   3.00    2   3.00    short   23  -425.32 -0.3419 46.00   1698.67 1691.4011   1704.1116   2   2013-10-08  0   1636.3851
W   2   2013-09-09  0   2013-11-18  0   3   11.00   97.18   129.0572    0.0596  0.116   2013-09-16  1725.23 1757.1072   1   8.00    2   7.00    average 41  414.5201    0.6668  74.00   1691.75 1655.5985   1688.9805   1   2013-11-25  0   1618.5959
M   2   2012-01-03  0   2013-02-04  0   21  14.00   501.7101    330.8972    0.4192  0.3409  2013-07-01  1698.4301   1527.6172   18  11.00   11  8.00    extended    32  683.73  1.4888  44.00   1691.75 1531.6484   1616.1792   1   2013-03-04  0   1462.0884

I want the above table contents to look like this:
```

> ```
> pinterval H   D   W   M
> phasetype 1   1   2   2
> abegdate  09/26/13    09/25/13    09/09/13    01/03/12
> abegdatehr    3   0   0   0
> penddate  09/27/13    10/01/13    11/18/13    02/04/13
> pendhour  1   0   0   0
> alength   12  3   3   21
> avglength 6   5   11  14
> achgprevhilo  -16.74  -37.98  97.18   501.7101
> avgchgprev    -20.9827    -55.4949    129.0572    330.8972
> achgprevhilopct   -0.98%  -2.19%  5.96%   41.92%
> avgchgprevpct -1.53%  -4.42%  11.60%  34.09%
> adatehilo 09/27/13    09/25/13    09/16/13    07/01/13
> ahilovalue    1687.11 1687.11 1725.23 1698.4301
> philovalue    1682.8673   1571.9751   1757.1072   1527.6172
> aperiodstohilo    6   1   1   18
> avgperiodstohilo  5   3   8   11
> anumhilos 4   2   2   11
> pnumhilos 3   3   7   8
> projphaselen  extended    short   average extended
> recperiodstohilo  3   23  41  32
> recchgprevhilo    -20.9827    -425.32 414.5201    683.73
> recchgprevhilopct -1.53%  -34.19% 66.68%  148.88%
> reclength 6.4786  46  74  44
> avalue    1691.75 1698.67 1691.75 1691.75
> LTL   1690.7904   1691.4011   1655.5985   1531.6484
> UTL   1694.8193   1704.1116   1688.9805   1616.1792
> nxtphstype    2   2   1   1
> nxtphsdate    09/27/13    10/08/13    11/25/13    03/04/13
> nxtphshour    2   0   0   0
> nxtphshilo    1709.5498   1636.3851   1618.5959   1462.0884
> ```

Do I use Pivot? If yes what is the syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to elaborate way more than you did. What does `H   D   W   M`  mean? Provide enough sample data in a tabular form to illustrate your desired result that you've already posted. And you can read about PIVOT and UNPIVOT syntax [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: thx peterm - H = Hours, D = Days, W = Weeks, M = Months. No joke, that's all the data that is in the table. I am somewhat familiar with Pivot but not sure how to use it when I really don't need an aggregate function, I just need the rows/columns flipped as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you first need to `UNPIVOT` your table and then `PIVOT` again. One of the complications when you unpivot columns with different data types is that you have to cast them all to the same datatype and most likely to transform some of them (e.g. dates, percentages etc) . In the example below `VARCHAR(32)` is used as a common data type. You might want to adjust it to your needs.

Here is a working query with only some of your columns:

```
WITH unpivot_phase AS
(
  SELECT property, pinterval, value
    FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT pinterval, 
           CAST(phasetype       AS VARCHAR(32)) phasetype,
           CAST(abegdate        AS VARCHAR(32)) abegdate,
           CAST(abegdatehr      AS VARCHAR(32)) abegdatehr,
           CAST(penddate        AS VARCHAR(32)) penddate,
           CAST(pendhour        AS VARCHAR(32)) pendhour,
           CAST(alength         AS VARCHAR(32)) alength,
           CAST(avglength       AS VARCHAR(32)) avglength,
           CAST(achgprevhilo    AS VARCHAR(32)) achgprevhilo,
           CAST(avgchgprev      AS VARCHAR(32)) avgchgprev,
           CAST(achgprevhilopct AS VARCHAR(32)) achgprevhilopct,
           CAST(avgchgprevpct   AS VARCHAR(32)) avgchgprevpct,
           CAST(adatehilo       AS VARCHAR(32)) adatehilo
           -- add rest of the columns here
      FROM phasepivot 
  ) s
  UNPIVOT
  ( 
    value FOR property IN (phasetype, abegdate, abegdatehr, 
                           penddate, pendhour, alength, avglength,
                           achgprevhilo, avgchgprev, achgprevhilopct, 
                           avgchgprevpct, adatehilo) -- add rest of the columns here
  ) u
)
SELECT property, H, D, W, M
  FROM
(
  SELECT property, pinterval, value
    FROM unpivot_phase
) s
PIVOT
(
  MAX(value) FOR pinterval IN (H, D, W, M)
) p
 ORDER BY 
  CASE property 
    WHEN 'phasetype'       THEN 1
    WHEN 'abegdate'        THEN 2
    WHEN 'abegdatehr'      THEN 3
    WHEN 'penddate'        THEN 4
    WHEN 'pendhour'        THEN 5
    WHEN 'alength'         THEN 6
    WHEN 'avglength'       THEN 7
    WHEN 'achgprevhilo'    THEN 8
    WHEN 'avgchgprev'      THEN 9
    WHEN 'achgprevhilopct' THEN 10 
    WHEN 'avgchgprevpct'   THEN 11
    WHEN 'adatehilo'       THEN 12
  END
```

Output:

```
|        PROPERTY |          H |          D |          W |          M |
|-----------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|       phasetype |          1 |          1 |          2 |          2 |
|        abegdate | 2013-09-26 | 2013-09-25 | 2013-09-09 | 2012-01-03 |
|      abegdatehr |          3 |          0 |          0 |          0 |
|        penddate | 2013-09-27 | 2013-10-01 | 2013-11-18 | 2013-02-04 |
|        pendhour |          1 |          0 |          0 |          0 |
|         alength |         12 |          3 |          3 |         21 |
|       avglength |       6.00 |       5.00 |      11.00 |      14.00 |
|    achgprevhilo |     -16.74 |     -37.98 |      97.18 |     501.71 |
|      avgchgprev |     -20.98 |     -55.49 |     129.06 |     330.90 |
| achgprevhilopct |      -0.98 |      -2.19 |       5.96 |      41.92 |
|   avgchgprevpct |      -1.53 |      -4.42 |      11.60 |      34.09 |
|       adatehilo | 2013-09-27 | 2013-09-25 | 2013-09-16 | 2013-07-01 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a90b6/16)** demo

Comment: peterm - brilliant! it worked. thx! Just one last nit...the pivoted table is sorted by property alpha asc. The order of the properties in the (manually) pivoted table from  my original post is needed. Obviously, I could add a column to phase pivot that includes an integer to sort by. However, I am having difficulty understanding where to place the SORT BY in the select statements with PIVOT at the bottom of your last SQL post?

Comment: @FrankZappa You're quite welcome :) See updated answer and sqlfiddle example. The strait-forward approach to preserving the correct order is just add `ORDER BY` with `CASE...END`. If you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.